# Where does The Toilet lead in New 52 Suicide Squad?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, suicide-squad, dc-rebirth

In New 52 [Suicide Squad #29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbSSq.jpg), Amanda Waller makes use of a portal nicknamed "The Toilet" as a plan B to bring a Thinker-controlled O.M.A.C down.

There is a hint that it may lead to "some other universe", but nothing specific at this time.

At the end of this issue, O.M.A.C and King Shark both fall into the Toilet. I don't remember seeing King Shark as a Task Force X member in New Suicide Squad (haven't read Suicide Squad Rebirth yet), and I don't know if O.M.A.C reappeared in some other series after that.

Do we know where this portal leads?

Have O.M.A.C. or King Shark appeared since then (in New 52 or Rebirth titles), perhaps providing some hint of where they went?

Comment: Is [this #29](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Suicide_Squad_Vol_4_2) or [this #29](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Suicide_Squad_Vol_5_29) the issue you are talking about? The former is part of The New 52, the latter is part of DC Rebirth. I'm guessing the former given your title, but you have both of those in your tags for the question, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: It's the New 52 one, I tagged Rebirth to open the question to this part of the continuity, in case the answer is hiding in there